# Can Kafka brokers store data not only in binary format but also Avro, JSON, and strings?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm very confused about Kafka brokers. I thought they store messages(data, record) as binary formats like 0100110111... (Some people may call them byte arrays, byte streams, arrays of bytes, etc)

As I am reading about Kafka Connect, it says that messages are stored in Avro object, JSON object, or a string in Kafka.

Kafka Definitive Guide :

> ... the worker then uses the configured converter to convert the record to either an Avro object, JSON object, or a string, and the result is then stored into Kafka. ... When the Connect Worker reads a record from Kafka, it uses the configured converter to convert the record from the format in Kafka(i.e. Avro, JSON, or string) to the Connect Data API record and then passes it to the sink connector, which inserts it into the destination system.

**Kafka brokers can store both binary data and Avro, JSON, and string?**

**Or JSON, Avro, and String are binary data?**

(I know about Producer/Consumer's serialization/deserialization. My question is about Broker's perspective only.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When data is shipped to Kafka Brokers, it is serialized from different data types 
 i.e avro/json/string/other data types into `bytearray` format before writing into log files.

Kafka topic log files will always have data stored into bytearray format. While reading via consumer, the bytearray data is deserialized to readable format i.e. string, avro, json etc.

Comment: Can Broker serialize data, too? I thought only Producer can serialize data. Maybe Connector (Worker) serialize Avro, JSON, or a string right before sending data to Broker?

Comment: Broker doesn't serialize or deserialize the data. Producer/Consumer does that job. Same way connect worker does that.

Comment: Thanks. Becoming clearer now. So for example, a record in mySQL will be turned into a Avro by connector, and then serialized into byte array to be stored in broker. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Since Kafka Stores key and value data, as simply a byte array, you can read it generically with a byte deserializer, and defer format specific deserialization until later.  Headers in the message can help with the deferral strategy as you can tell yourself key info or even the format of the data for subsequent deserialization on demand, or in a place that doesn't directly impact the performance of your consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Avro itself has a JSON like data model, so we can say they are similar. However, Avro can be represented as JSON and binary form as well, so it's the answer for your question.